# How to synchronize execution of two methods in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, thread-safety

I need to synchronize two methods in Java so that any threads could run any of these methods in parallel, but at any moment of time only one method would work. Here is the example:

```
public void one(){
 // any number of threads can be here if two() is not executed
}

public void two(){
 // any number of threads can be here if one() is not executed
}
```

How to synchronized methods like this? With synchronized only one thread can be executed at any moment of time.

Comment: What do you expect to happen to the caller of  `methodOne` when `methodTwo` is being "used" ?  Let's say that we have plenty of threads running `methodTwo`, what should happen to the callers of `methodOne`? Should we let them starve until some timeout?

Comment: Depending on the specifics of your case, you may want to consider a `ReadWriteLock`.

Comment: Yes, I want them to starve until some timeout. Thanks for pointing the answer. This question is already answered there.